# What is the advantage of specifying two types when creating a typedef'd struct?

Tags: c, struct, coding-style, typedef, c11

**example 1:**

```
struct T{
    int a;
};
```

creates the type **struct T**

---

**example 2:**

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} T;
```

creates the type **T**

---

**example 3:**

```
typedef struct T{
    int a;
} T;
```

creates both the types **struct T** and **T**

---

I tend to see example 3 a lot, and I'm not sure why someone would choose it over example 1 or 2.

- Are there any advantages you gain from doing it this way?
- Are there reasons people do this for compatibility?
- Is it advantageous for some kind of scoping reason?

I would like to avoid doing it the **example 3** way, because it is less maintenance on the type, and it restricts multiple ways of declaring the same thing.  However, I would reconsider it, if there are benefits to this "double naming" technique.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion really. Mine is that example 3 is fine; it reduces the possibility for errors and doesn't have any downsides apart from being unaesthetic to some beholders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tend to see example 3 a lot, and I'm not sure why someone would
>   choose it over example 1 or 2.
>
> - Are there any advantages you gain from doing it this way?

I hold this truth to be self-evident, namely that cumbersome code is cumbersome. Everyone would prefer to write

```
T object;
```

instead of

```
struct T object;
```

However, a hard-core C coder might think *hey, `T` is a struct, better call it like that* and also, it mitigates the chance for confusion you'd get when doing

```
struct {int a; } T; typedef int T;
```

> - Are there reasons people do this for compatibility?

Yes. This way, structs in C can be used like they would be used in C++.

> - Is it advantageous for some kind of scoping reason?

no, not that I'd be aware of.